# Transcribe a short clip of a StarCraft match

Tags: internet-slang

[Here](https://media5jvqbd.fmkorea.com/files/attach/new/20201206/486616/2875084395/3243923689/7bbf4194e50166f029a22e1b3ea6328f.mp4?d) is a legendary video clip from a [StarCraft: Brood war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft:_Brood_War) match. (8 seconds)

[전용준](https://starcraft.fandom.com/wiki/Jeon), also known as "Jeon" is a professional StarCraft caster who's commentating in this clip.

Can someone please tell me what this guy is trying to say?

All I can catch and recognize is "앞마당이... 앞마당이 계속...".

Comment: Google 박태민 앞마당 깨졌죠, and you will find it.

Comment: @Klmo Thanks, but how did you find this? Are you a StarCraft fan too?

Comment: I was. I used to watch StarCraft matches, so I could catch 해처리, 빨간색, and 앞마당 깨졌죠 without difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 김동수: 저글링을 꾸준히 생산하면 이거 역전 나옵니다!

> 전용준: 네 이것이 벌써 해처리 빨간색 빠빨간색 해처리 빨간색 일보직전입니다 박태민 앞마당을 날립니까 박태민 앞마당 깨졌죠~!